# Mongodb query to get information about circural dependency

Tags: mongodb, dependencies, correlation

I have collection like this in MongoDB:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "616309f71b021c754992bfca"},
    "correlatedNodes": [
      {
        "type": "IS_ULTIMATELY_CONSOLIDATED_BY",
        "nodes": ["I07WOS4YJ0N7YRFE7309"]
      }
    ],
    "fromTaskId": 20,
    "nodeName": "5493000U0YGG4VEQOX65"
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "616309f71b021c754992bfcb"},
    "correlatedNodes": [
      {
        "type": "IS_DIRECTLY_CONSOLIDATED_BY",
        "nodes": ["529900P6OUCFPVWCFE19", "8945007IZBKFQUQLIP85"]
      },
      {
        "type": "IS_ULTIMATELY_CONSOLIDATED_BY",
        "nodes": ["529900P6OUCFPVWCFE19"]
      }
    ],
    "fromTaskId": 20,
    "nodeName": "89450012XZ2GPWGIGH37"
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "616309f71b021c754992bfcc"},
    "correlatedNodes": [
      {
        "type": "IS_ULTIMATELY_CONSOLIDATED_BY",
        "nodes": ["815600C9588783AB0210"]
      },
      {
        "type": "IS_DIRECTLY_CONSOLIDATED_BY",
        "nodes": ["815600C9588783AB0210"]
      }
    ],
    "fromTaskId": 20,
    "nodeName": "815600228127946DFF05"
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "616309f71b021c754992bfcd"},
    "correlatedNodes": [
      {
        "type": "IS_ULTIMATELY_CONSOLIDATED_BY",
        "nodes": ["549300LI58A0MHGHTZ98"]
      }
    ],
    "fromTaskId": 20,
    "nodeName": "549300NV4OCF16TAS048"
  }
]
```

It's possible to get information about circular dependency using query.
For example nodeName: 5493000U0YGG4VEQOX65 have list where exists node name 89450012XZ2GPWGIGH37 and this node have also list contains 5493000U0YGG4VEQOX65.
I want to find this scenario and list nodeNames where this situation occures.

Comment: Can you provide a query that you have attempted

Comment: aggregation with a graphLookup stage should get you that information.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#-graphlookup--aggregation-)

1. `$unwind` the `correlatedNodes` and `correlatedNodes.nodes` for further processing
2. perform `$graphLookup`; with `restrictSearchWithMatch` to stop the recusive search when reach self node

```
{
    "$graphLookup": {
        "from": "collection",
        "startWith": "$correlatedNodes.nodes",
        "connectFromField": "correlatedNodes.nodes",
        "connectToField": "nodeName",
        "as": "nodeChain",
        "depthField": "depth",
        "restrictSearchWithMatch": {
            "nodeName": { $ne: "$nodeName" }
        }
    }
}
```

3. use `$reduce` to determine whether the `nodeChain` is a circular one; You can achieve this by checking `nodeChain.correlatedNodes.nodes` equals to the outermost`nodeName` or not
4. `$match` the result in step 3 to find the circular cases.

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4R7emnzPDGS) for your reference.